# mongodb query for object properties inside array inside of an object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Datastructure:

```
Document:
{
  "projects": {
    "projectName" : String,
    "employees": [String]
  }
}
```

Now i want to find a document which has a project with name "project1" and an employee "employee1".

When i try to query by only one property from the nested projects object, it seems to be no problem.
But as soon as i want also to access the nested array. Queries start to fail.

```
db.documents.find({'projects': { $elemMatch: { name: "project1", $elemMatch: { employees: 'employee1' } } })
```

I work with meteor collections, so it looks like this:

```
Documents.findOne({'projects': { $elemMatch: { name: "project1", $elemMatch: { employees: 'employee1' } } })
```

I also tried this simple approach:

```
db.collection.find({
  "projects.projectName": "project1",
  "projects.employees": "employee1"
})
```

but it didn't work.

EDIT: As J.F. suggested. This Query is correct. But i had a Schema Error. After correcting it, everything worked fine.

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IIC2zRv4VZB) what are you looking for?

Comment: Kinda yes and i already tried this, but for me this Query doesn't return anything. Maybe it is due to Meteor Collections?

Comment: Oh men.. i found the problem... it was due to a schema error, your solution is right

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $in operator
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

```
db.collection.find({
  "projects.projectName": "project1",
  "projects.employees": {$in: ["employee1"]}
})
```